# Word CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FileNew")

Tags: vba, ms-word, commandbar

I am using the following command in Word VBA but in the latest version of Word 365 (version 2005):

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FileNew")
```

but this does not give the same Backstage page as clicking File > New.

When you click File > New you get the choice of Office and Personal templates but the `ExecuteMso ("FileNew")` does not display the Personal templates.

Any ideas on how to get Backstage page as per clicking File > New? I can't use `SendKeys` because command has to work in multiple languages and ribbon is language specific.

Comment: Why do you need to execute code to show the Backstage view? There is a built-in command to do just that, though it isn't on the ribbon, New From Template (FileNew). There are registry settings to remove the Office/Featured templates from the Backstage view and set the default tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use Documents.Add which allows you to specify the template, or Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileNew) which allows you to choose the template.

Comment: Thanks but the client wants to see the Backstage view of New to select a template. It's frustrating that Microsoft make these type of annoying little changes for no good reason (other than to promote their templates, which are of no interest or benefit in a corporate environment)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to activate the `File` tab programmatically first. The [IRibbonUI.ActivateTabMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.activatetabmso) method activates the specified built-in tab. Read more about that in the [Ribbon Extensibility in Office 2010: Tab Activation and Auto-Scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691834(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Only then you can run the built-in command - `FileNew`.

Comment: Thanks i will investigate and see how i get on